# How to work with files which belong to the subuser namespace under Linux?

Tags: linux, docker

I am using `docker` on `ubuntu 16.04` with user id mapping (user namepsaces) enabled. I have following settings:

**/etc/passwd**

`myusername:x:1000:1000:,,,:/home/myusername:/bin/bash`

**/etc/subuid**

`myusername:100000:65536`

**/etc/subguid**

`myusername:100000:65536`

When I start a container the files are being correctly mapped from 0 (root) to my subuid 100000.

**host**

`-rw-r--r-- 1 100000 100000 0 Mär 30 13:05 testfile`

**container**

`rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 30 13:05 testfile`

I can read the file on the host machine, but I cannot edit it. My assumption was that `100000` is "my" subuid, so I can edit those files. How can I achieve that those files are accessible by `myusername` without sudo?

Comment: Normally it's not a good practice to modify volume contents (with normal user). You can change them with root anyway.

Comment: This is intented for development only. I want to start at container with php-fpm in it and edit the files in my IDE on the host.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how to fix this with user namespace mapping but you can work around it with ACL's.

If you don't mind leaking some UID information into the container, you can add an ACL to the directory for your host user. ACL's sit on top of the standard POSIX permissions.

To set a default ACL on the parent directory, that new entries inherit:

```
setfacl -d -m u:1000:rwx volume_dir/
```

To set the ACL on all existing files and directories in a directory:

```
setfacl -R -m u:1000:rwX volume_dir/
```

The `X` auto detects directories and sets them to executable but skips making files executable. Unfortunately this type of differentiation is not available on the default ACL.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a solution using [user namespace remapping](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/)?

When Docker is configured with user namespace remapping, it maps the root user inside a container to a non-root user on the host. In your setup, the root user (UID 0) inside the container is remapped to UID 100000 on the host. That is why files created inside the container by the root user appear to be owned by UID 100000 on the host:

```bash
Host (Ubuntu 16.04)
│
├─ /etc/passwd
│  └─ myusername:x:1000:1000:,,,:/home/myusername:/bin/bash
│
├─ /etc/subuid
│  └─ myusername:100000:65536
│
└─ /etc/subgid
   └─ myusername:100000:65536

Docker Container
│
└─ Files (e.g., testfile)
   ├─ On Host: -rw-r--r-- 1 100000 100000 0 Mär 30 13:05 testfile
   └─ In Container: rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 30 13:05 testfile
```

You would need to enable `myusername` on the host (with a UID of 1000) to access files owned by UID 100000 (the remapped root user from the Docker container). There are a few approaches to handle this:

- One was [mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43130742/6309): Use ACLs to grant `myusername` access to files created by the Docker container. Example: `setfacl -m u:myusername:rwx /path/to/file`.
  By setting ACLs on the host system, you can grant specific permissions to your regular user (UID 1000) for files and directories created by the Docker container, irrespective of the standard file ownership.
  That means your regular user can read, write, or execute files that are technically owned by a different user ID (the remapped UID from the Docker container).
- Another approach is to create a group on the host that includes both `myusername` and the Docker user (UID 100000). Make sure files created by Docker are group-writable and the shared group is the owner.
- Or: use a script or manual commands to periodically change ownership of files created by Docker from UID 100000 to `myusername`.
- Or: [Bind Mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) with specific UID/GID: when mounting host directories into the container, you can specify the UID/GID with which files should be written. But that seems more complex.

Of these options, ACLs are often the most flexible and least intrusive, as they do not require changing the existing user and group ownerships which Docker relies on.

```bash
# Grant myusername read, write, and execute permissions on a specific file
setfacl -m u:myusername:rwx /path/to/docker/file

# To apply it to all new files in a directory
setfacl -m d:u:myusername:rwx /path/to/docker/directory
```

That command sets an ACL that explicitly grants `myusername` the specified permissions on files created by Docker, regardless of the standard Linux file permissions.

---

> But WHY doesn't his subuid file now do what he wants?
>
> His `/etc/subuid` file contains `myusername:100000:65536`, so according to your explanation, his user should already have access to files owned by 100000, right? I have the same problem.

The `/etc/subuid` file is used to define a range of user IDs that Docker can map its internal user IDs to, on the host system.
In your setup, `myusername:100000:65536` means that Docker can map user IDs within its containers to any of the 65536 UIDs starting from 100000 on the host. That mapping is used to isolate container processes from the host system for security reasons.

Despite `myusername` being associated with the range starting at UID 100000 in `/etc/subuid`, it does *not* automatically grant `myusername` access to files owned by UID 100000. That mapping is about isolation, not access control. It makes sure processes within the Docker container that run as a particular user (e.g., root as UID 0) are mapped to a non-privileged user on the host (e.g., UID 100000), but it does not imply file access permissions.

Linux file permissions are based on the actual UID and GID of the process trying to access the file. Even though `myusername` is associated with the UID range in `/etc/subuid`, when acting on the host system, `myusername` operates under its actual UID (e.g., 1000).
Therefore, if a file on the host is owned by UID 100000, `myusername` (UID 1000) does not have permissions to access it if standard Linux file permissions do not allow it.

ACLs offer a way to extend traditional Unix permissions. By setting an ACL, you can grant specific additional permissions to `myusername` for files owned by UID 100000, without altering the standard file ownership and permission model.

To grant `myusername` access to files owned by the Docker-mapped UID (100000), ACLs or other permission management methods need to be used. That approach respects the security model implemented through user namespace remapping while addressing the practical need for file access.

---

> You say it is about isolation, but it is not clear what role `myusername` has regarding uid 100000, if any. Would it behave any different if `/etc/subuid` read `anotherusername:100000:65536`?

The entry `myusername:100000:65536` in `/etc/subuid` indicates that Docker is allowed to use the UID range of 100000 to 165535 for mapping UIDs within the Docker containers started by `myusername`. That mapping is important for user namespace remapping, which Docker uses to provide a layer of isolation between container processes and the host system.

The primary purpose of this mapping is to enhance security. If a process inside the container, running as root (UID 0), tries to interact with the host system, it will do so with the remapped UID (e.g., 100000), which typically has no significant permissions on the host. That remapping prevents a containerized process from having the same level of access or privileges as the host system's root or other significant users: it provides a strong isolation boundary.

If `/etc/subuid` were to read `anotherusername:100000:65536`, it would mean that Docker containers started by `anotherusername` could use the same UID range for remapping. The actual behavior in terms of user ID remapping would not change. Docker would still remap the internal container UIDs to the specified range, regardless of whether it is `myusername` or `anotherusername`.
However, the ownership of files created by containers would be linked to `anotherusername` instead of `myusername`.

Regardless of which username is specified in `/etc/subuid`, the standard Linux file permissions apply. That means neither `myusername` nor `anotherusername` would have access to files owned by the UID 100000, unless additional permissions (like standard Unix permissions, ACLs, group memberships, etc.) are explicitly set.

So, the username specified in `/etc/subuid` determines which host user's Docker containers can use the specified UID range for namespace remapping.
It is about allocating a range of UIDs for container use, for isolation and security. The actual file access permissions are still governed by Linux's standard file permission mechanisms, and having a username associated with a UID range in `/etc/subuid` does not grant automatic access to files owned by UIDs within that range.

Comment: ACL seems nice, but it doesn't allow the docker process (running as root) to edit host1000-owned files. maybe I should set the ACL for host 100000 as well? (in which case, what's the point of the "subordination" in subuids?)

Comment: @CapiEtheriel I confirm that, unless you map docker root to host1000 uid, it won't work. It is better for host1000 to be in a common group id, with read/write access through the group.

Comment: But WHY doesn't his subuid file now do what he wants? His `/etc/subuid` file contains `myusername:100000:65536`, so according to your explanation, his user should already have access to files owned by 100000, right? I have the same problem.

Comment: @Berwyn I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you so much!

Comment: You say it is about isolation, but it is not clear what role `myusername` has in regard to uid 100000, if any. Would it behave any different if /etc/subuid read `anotherusername:100000:65536`?

Comment: @CapiEtheriel I have edited the answer to address your comment/question.

Answer (score 1):

You can add your user "myusername" under the sudo group.
Add the below line in **/etc/sudoers** file.

```
myusername ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```